# You cannot accept payments using this API as it is no longer supported in India

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

Controller file:

```
public function stripePost(Request $request)
{
Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

Stripe\Charge::create([
    "amount" => 100 * 100,
    "currency" => "usd",
    "source" => $request->stripeToken,
    "description" => "Thanks for payment "
]);

Session::flash('success', 'Payment successful!');

return back();
}
```

`stripe.blade.php` file:

```
<h1>Pay Using Your Card</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default credit-card-box">
            <div class="panel-heading display-table">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Payment Details</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                @if (Session::has('success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success text-center">
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
                        <p>{{ Session::get('success') }}</p>
                    </div>
                @endif

                <form role="form" action="{{ route('stripe.post') }}"
                      method="post"
                      class="require-validation"
                      data-cc-on-file="false"
                      data-stripe-publishable-key="{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}"
                      id="payment-form">
                    @csrf

                    <div class='form-row row'>
                        <div class='col-xs-12 form-group required'>
                            <label class='control-label'>Name on Card</label> <input
                                class='form-control' size='4' type='text'>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-row row'>
                        <div class='col-xs-12 form-group card required'>
                            <label class='control-label'>Card Number</label> <input
                                autocomplete='off' class='form-control card-number' size='20'
                                type='text'>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-row row'>
                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group cvc required'>
                            <label class='control-label'>CVC</label> <input autocomplete='off'
                                                                          class='form-control card-cvc'
                                                                          placeholder='ex. 311' size='4'
                                                                          type='text'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group expiration required'>
                            <label class='control-label'>Expiration Month</label> <input
                                class='form-control card-expiry-month' placeholder='MM' size='2'
                                type='text'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='col-xs-12 col-md-4 form-group expiration required'>
                            <label class='control-label'>Expiration Year</label> <input
                                class='form-control card-expiry-year' placeholder='YYYY' size='4'
                                type='text'>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class='form-row row'>
                        <div class='col-md-12 error form-group hide'>
                            <div class='alert-danger alert'>Please correct the errors and try
                                again.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Pay Now</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

$(function () {

        /*------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------
        Stripe Payment Code
        --------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------*/

        var $form = $(".require-validation");

        $('form.require-validation').bind('submit', function (e) {
            var $form = $(".require-validation"),
                inputSelector = ['input[type=email]', 'input[type=password]',
                    'input[type=text]', 'input[type=file]',
                    'textarea'].join(', '),
                $inputs = $form.find('.required').find(inputSelector),
                $errorMessage = $form.find('div.error'),
                valid = true;
            $errorMessage.addClass('hide');

            $('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');
            $inputs.each(function (i, el) {
                var $input = $(el);
                if ($input.val() === '') {
                    $input.parent().addClass('has-error');
                    $errorMessage.removeClass('hide');
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });

            if (!$form.data('cc-on-file')) {
                e.preventDefault();
                Stripe.setPublishableKey($form.data('stripe-publishable-key'));
                Stripe.createToken({
                    number: $('.card-number').val(),
                    cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
                    exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
                    exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
                }, stripeResponseHandler);
            }

        });

        /*------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------
        Stripe Response Handler
        --------------------------------------------
        --------------------------------------------*/
        function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
            if (response.error) {
                $('.error')
                    .removeClass('hide')
                    .find('.alert')
                    .text(response.error.message);
            } else {
                /* token contains id, last4, and card type */
                var token = response['id'];

                $form.find('input[type=text]').empty();
                $form.append("");
                $form.get(0).submit();
            }
        }

    });

`web.php` file:

```
Route::get('/stripe/{totalprice}', [HomeController::class, 'stripe']);
Route::post('stripe',  [HomeController::class,'stripePost'])->name('stripe.post');
```

Comment: Is there meant to be a question in here somewhere? I mean if you are asking about the error in the title what is the question exactly? I would imagine this is not an issue in your code but an issue in trying to do something that Stripe does not support (and the solution is to stop doing things that are not supported)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the public [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/charges-api), Merchants in India can't use Charges API anymore.